# LUIS: connect to staging environment using the LuisClient

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to choose between staging and production environment when I create a `LuisClient` instance from Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS nuget package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on LUIS portal, the difference between calls to staging vs production is by using a `staging=true` value in query string, for example for a project in Europe:

```
https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/myAppId?subscription-key=mySubscriptionKey&staging=true&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=
```

This variable is **not** available in `Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS`:

[image: LUIS lib]